# How is os.path.file implemented?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory-structure

I am working on a program which needs to do several searches through a folder that may contain well over 20,000 files to see if a certain file exists. Does os.path.isfile iterate through every file in a directory, or does it use a more efficient method? And would dividing these 20,000 files between different sub-directories speed up that lookup that isfile has to do?

Note: I am using python 3

Comment: You have to look at the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)

Comment: As far as I can tell the documentation gives no information as to how methods are implemented.

Comment: Please read the documentation. For one thing, `isfile` operates on a single path. It does not do anything like recursively descending into the filesystem.

Comment: `os.path.isfile(path)` is a bool which return if the current path contains a valid file or not. It does'nt iterate through the folders files.

Comment: A little bit of research would have got you to https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/genericpath.py, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/posixpath.py and https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ntpath.py

Answer (score 1):

Internally it uses [stat system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)) and works with the speed that the filesystem and OS provide.

Whether splitting huge directory in multiple subdirectories helps speed things up very much depends on the OS and the filesystem implementation. But usually yes — the less files in a directory the better.